# How to rotate tiles in GeoServer ImageMosaic

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff

I am starting a project relatively "fresh" to GeoServer. We have a large number of tiled (seabed) images to load up to GeoServer using the ImageMosaic plugin in order to make a seabed mosaic. We know the geolocation of all the images as well as the scaling. We can calculate the required rotation offsets.

When I add a rotation factor to the world file or GeoTIFF header I expect the images to be rendered rotated or "warped" but do not seem to be able to get anything other than unrotated images.

How should I prepare my image mosaic folder so that all of the images are rendered rotated? Do I need to rotate them myself before uploading to GeoServer or can I tell GeoServer/ImageMosaic to do this for me?

Answer (score 1):

Ciao Jeremy,
currently the ImageMosaic can handle fine raster where the grid-to-world transformation is scale and translate, hence now skew or rotation.

In light of this limitation I would suggest to perform a warp of your images upfront using, as an instance gdal_warp.

I have worked myself with Side Scan Sonar data in the past and I always used this approach even because otherwise at runtime it would be expensive to apply a very complex transformation just for visualizing/extracting. Btw, make sure to retile and add overviews properly.

I few useful links:
http://goo.gl/74XUPq
http://goo.gl/wdVjSd

Regards,
Simone.